# A binning (sorting) algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Rules: A conveyor belt is giving you little boxes. They are labeled for your convenience: Box $1$, Box $2$,... For your inconvenience, though, you can't see the number (from $1...n$) hidden in it. You can sort the boxes into $n$ bins as you like. You may pause the belt at any time to resort the boxes. As soon as one bin contains a minimum of $k$ boxes (or more, doesn't hurt) all with the same number in it, and no other number in that bin, a siren goes off and you are declared programmer of the month. :-)

Here is a very stupid but surefire algorithm: Fetch at least $n(k-1)+1$ boxes and try out all permutations with $k$ boxes in bin 1 and $k-1$ in the rest of bins, in any order.

I guess you can do better than $O((nk)!)$?

Comment: The algorithm you describe already does a bit better than $\mathcal O((nk)!)$, actually -- and of course the order of the boxes in the rest of the bins doesn't matter, so if you avoid repeating the same elements in the bin 1, you get down to $\mathcal O\left(\binom{n(k-1) + 1}{n}\right)$. You could probably do a small bit better (by using other bins), but I would be surprised if you could do *much* better; the method gives you no 'partial information' at all.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: I think you need $k$ on the bottom of that expression, not $n$.  This is much better than $O((nk)!)$ :)

Comment: If the number of all boxes is $n(k−1)+1$, then $\binom{n(k-1) + 1\ \ }{k}$ number of tries is needed in the worst case. That can be shown by a simple adversary argument.

Comment: "You can sort the boxes into $n$ bins as you like". What is the significance of $n$? All comments above stay the same if we have only 1 bin. Is the following an equivalent story? "You are given infinitely many distinct boxes. Each of them contains a number from 1 to $n$, which you cannot see. You can select any $k$ boxes to put into a testing bin. If all $k$ boxes have the same number, a siren goes off and you are declared programmer of the month. Otherwise, you can try again with another set of $k$ boxes. What is the minimum number of tries in which you can make sure the siren will go off?"

Comment: In my story above, only $k$ boxes are considered since putting more than $k$ boxes in the testing bin cannot improve the situation.

Comment: Speaking of adversary, I realize I should have clarified two points: The Belt of Doom is (hope I remember the terms correctly) an online adversary, i.e. assume it knows your strategy, but can only react to the actions you did (if you utilize random-dependent actions). If it is easier, you can also assume the belt acts randomly. Also, it's neither the number of boxes that count nor the atomar repacking actions (you might have to move more than one box to a new bin to get a new state), but just the number of guess states.

Comment: Indeed, the binomial is much better, but probably still to high for practical purposes. Still pondering about Apass Jack's comment. Point is that in a more realistic (but also far more complicated to elaborate here) setting there *is* some partial information - think of an Aouga horn warning you that there are already two different numbers in the bin, and *that* will honk far lower than k. So it makes sense to try more bins in parallel.

Comment: "think of an Aouga horn warning you that there are already two different numbers in the bin, and that will honk far lower than k" -- I don't follow.  It sounds like you're saying you can get information about the set of boxes in a bin when the k-or-more-same-numbered-boxes-and-no-other-boxes siren *doesn't* go off -- you can, but only when there are at least k boxes in the bin.  And then the only information you get is "there are at least 2 distinct numbers among these k or more boxes", which doesn't seem to me enough to be useful in a pigeonhole-principle-based attack.

Comment: Clarification: Lets say that you must collect 6 equal numbers, then in the more realistic setting you already get a warning when 4 numbers are NOT equal. (The values are random :-) But now that I think of it, you still could use just one sorting bin...

Comment: Ah, so when you're talking about the "aouga horn", you're talking about a different version of the problem than the one in your question.  Yes, this version of the problem gives you a lot more information to potentially exploit.